# Removing body class based on ajax cart change woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a class with

```
add_filter( 'body_class', '' )
```

But I want to remove the class if the product is removed from the cart with ajax. The filter inside the function is not working. Can you point what is wrong?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'prevent_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function prevent_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    $blocked_product_ids = array(
        15530 
    );

    $product_title = get_the_title( $product_id );

    if ( in_array( $product_id, $blocked_product_ids ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wc_add_notice( 'notice', 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    } else {
        add_filter( 'body_class', function ( array $classes ) {
            if ( in_array( 'hide_paypal', $classes ) ) {
                unset( $classes[ array_search( 'hide_paypal', $classes ) ] );
            }

            return $classes;
        } );
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely this is an ordering issue: `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` runs after the `body` tag has been printed, or in a separate request, so the `body_class` filter doesn't run.

You'll likely need to move the changing of the body class to JavaScript.